# Failed to install jdk on windows 8 64 bit os

Tags: java

I am using 64 bit windows 8, i have downloaded jdk-7u51..x64.exe from official site of oracle. but as soon as i run the set up it says

"The app can't run on your pc,check with the software publisher"

whats is the problem why 64 bit jdk is not able to install on 64 bit windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest java gives some issues in Eclipse [Use this link to download in java](https://jdk6.java.net/download.html)

Comment: successfully install older version of jdk, waiting until oracle fixed issue with windows 8